# Azure ML R Model Train & Score Web Service

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I created the the Azure Machine Learning sample "[R Model Train & Score](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/R-Model-Train-Score-2)" from the gallery and followed the tutorial.  However, when I setup, deploy the web service ( as [New] Preview) and test, I get the error:

> Score Model (RPackage) : Given path to R installation not found on machine or R executable not at this location

The classic deployment works fine.  Any ideas on how to get the [New] Preview deployment example to run as a web service?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a bug. We are investigating this issue and will let you know as soon as fix is deployed